# Como inserir em uma classe com a anotação @Embeddable em uma tabela relacional criada no banco pela anotação @JoinTable criada em outra classe?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa noite!

Preciso evoluir um sistema adicionando os atributos de uma classe anotada com @Embeddable Dates em duas tabelas relacionais no banco de dados mysql chamadas de person_phone e person_email, os atributos são data inicial e final.

A explicação para isso é que, as duas tabelas foram criadas com a anotação @JoinTable na classe @Entity Person para estabelecer uma associação entre as classes @Entity Email e @Entity Phone resultante em um relacionamento no banco de dados com as tabelas person_phone e person_email.

O sistema possui arquitetura JPA implementada por hibernate.

A proposta é embutir os atributos da Classe @Embeddable Dates não na Classe @Entity Person, mas nas tabelas person_phone e person_email criadas pela anotação @JoinTable nesta classe @Entity Person.

Estou usando lombok para métodos e construtores das classes.

Segue o código:

Classe @Entity Person:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Long id;

 @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
 @Embedded
 @AttributeOverrides(value = {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "firstName", column = @Column(name = "first_name")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "lastName", column = @Column(name = "last_name"))
 })
 private PersonName personName;

 @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "person_phone", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id"))
 private List<Phone> phone;

 @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "person_email", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "email_id"))
 private List<Email> email;
}
```

Classe @Embeddable PersonName:

```
 @Data
 @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
 @Builder
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @Embeddable
 public class PersonName implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 30)
    @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Size(min = 20, max = 100)
    @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String lastName;
 }
```

Classes Associadas @Entity Phone e @Entity Email:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  private String typePhone;

  @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
  private String numberPhone;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;
}
```

A Classe seguinte é a @Embeddable que contem os atributos de datas de início e fim de registro:

```
 @Data
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @EqualsAndHashCode
 @Builder
 @Embeddable
 public class Dates {

   @Column(name = "initial_dt")
   @NotNull(message = "It cannot be null.")
   private LocalDateTime initial_date;

   @Column(name = "final_dt")   
   private LocalDateTime final_date;
 }
```

O sistema está funcionando perfeitamente, acessando o banco de dados e criando as tabelas, a minha dúvida é em relação a essa operação da classe @Embeddable se é possível inseri-la em @JoinTable ou se é preciso mapear no sistema as duas tabelas relacionais que foram criadas no banco. Aberto a sugestão e aguardo.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Parece-me que a melhor opção seja mapear as associações como entidades. Embora isso aumente a quantidade de código, você terá maior flexibilidade e controle. O Hibernate é muito vasto, tem muitos recursos, mas desconheço, alguma forma de mapear atributos em JoinTables e mesmo que exista tal recurso, sempre existe o risco de existir alguma limitação em se utilizar alguns recursos combinados, inclusive com objetos Embeddables.

Nesse cenário, seriam mapeadas duas entidades, PersonPhone e PersonEmail.

Comment: Entendi a sua explicação.
Mapear as classes relacionais no banco de dados podem dar mais opções de gerenciamento, claro que utilizar recursos como @JoinTable também são facilitadores, mas realmente a combinação de recursos excessiva pode aumentar a complexidade.
Vou seguir a dica e mapear as classes relacionais do banco em entidades na aplicação.
Obrigado pela dica.